# How to use RTC plugin from jenkins pipeline groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, rtc, jenkins-pipeline

I know I can use scm polling via a Jenkins RTC plugin, I'm just wondering if there's an example of how to do this via the groovy script for the pipeline plugin?

For example:

```
node{
   stage 'Checkout'
   git url: 'https://github.com/whatever/myrepo.git'
 ...
 }
```

Something like above but instead of git, you use rtc toolkit with prod url and specify a stream or a workspace... Cannot find an example anywhere and not sure how to go about implementing it via api (or if that's even possible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the snippet generator is a bit misleading in that it does not generate all that you need. For example, based on what was generated I used this in the pipeline:

```
node {
    teamconcert([buildDefinition: 'TestStream', value: 'buildDefinition'])
}
```

If you use it as is you will get this exception:

```
RTC : checkout...
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCScm.checkout(RTCScm.java:1948)
    atorg.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The syntax that you require is this:

```
node {
    teamconcert([
        buildType: [
            buildDefinition: 'TestStream',
            value: 'buildDefinition'
       ]
    ])
}
```

Team concert expects things to be wrapped in a 'buildType'. I found this in a forum answer on jazz.net, have not seen it documented anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There is a snippet code generator right there in the pipeline plugin, took me a while to find it, but it will generate the groovy code for any Jenkins task... Rtc is listed under teamconcert: Team Concert, just scroll down to the bottom and tick the Snippet Generator checkbox!